# You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle with invalid or missing signing information for some of its files

Tags: android, google-play, apk, google-console-developer

i'm getting this error when i try to upload my app update in Google Console  "Upload Fail" You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle with invalid or missing signing information for some of its files. You need to create a valid signed APK or Android App Bundle. Find out more about signing.

Answer (score 1):

Your APK has to be signed by your production private key. This is how Google knows that you built the APK and will allow it to go to your users. This is a safe guard from someone putting up a fake APK in your store listing.

The Play Developer Console will show you the signature of the key so you can compare it to keys and find the correct one to sign your APK with.

Here is some [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) on signing your APK.